# Show that a language is not regular using Myhill-Nerode Theorem

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

I'd like to show that the language below is not regular using Myhill-Nerode Theorem. How can I do that?

```
Let Σ = {0, 1}. 
Let L = {ww|w ∈ Σ*}
```

I am not sure where or how to go about this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: I use the notation and terminology of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) on the Myhill-Nerode theorem. Show that for this language $L$, the equivalence relation $R_L$ has infinitely many equivalence classes. Use the fact that if $u,v\in L$, $u\ne v$, and $|u|=|v|$, then $uu\in L$, but $vu\notin L$, so $u$ is a distinguishing extension for $u$ and $v$.